# Buggines and Instability of Microsoft LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am noticing a great deal of instability and bugginess in LUIS web interface. I created a new entity of type 'list' and now when I click on the entity, it takes me to the entity detail page, but also throws a server error. Also notice that I cannot add any more rows as the 'Add' button is disabled. I have similar problems training the model sometime, where it throws server errors and does not train for a long time. My question is: Even though I understand LUIS is a new technology being developed fast, is it stable enough to try to build working prototypes? It is extremely frustrating that product is buggy and there is not much help available.

[image]

Comment: Did you try contacting the support?

Comment: Have you tried recently? There was an issue that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To contact LUIS support, click the "Support" link in the top nav menu and enter your question in the pop-up window.

[image: Contact LUIS Support]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments and method of contacting the LUIS team with a general inquiry, the current [General Availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#General_availability_.28GA.29) Date (GA) for LUIS (i.e. a stable and non-preview platform) is tentatively planned for late this Fall. Similarly GA for Bot Framework and additional (but not all) Cognitive Service APIs is tentatively at late Fall as well.

I believe you can find a little more information on GA from this [talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2017/B8097) at Build 2017. The segment on upcoming features and what have you comes around the 21 minute mark. The talk also includes a lot of coverage on the newly released features and other notes on the roadmap.